# Which type of Flash animation performs best for games?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm making a multiplayer flash game in Actionscript 3.0, using Flash CS4 IDE.

I'm not sure what kind of animation would perform best (higher frames per second) in a game.  Frame based or maybe use the motion tween, also would it be best to do say the motion tweens by calling a frame or by calling a method with the animation code in it?

Comment: Frame base, don't use filters, and don't put too many clips into scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better framerates:

- move your game sprites with code, a little bit every frame
- use PNG source art instead of vector, so you can set stage quality to LOW with no visible aliasing
- use scrollrect to eliminate drawing objects outside the visible bounds of your game
- remove objects from the display list, don't just set visible=false
- recycle objects in your code instead of constantly creating new instances.  Learn about using object pools

Answer (score 0):

we meet again :)

Use bitmaps and containers

Use cache as bitmap for vector movieclips if you don't change their size and it has a lot of load.

Try to avoid filters and lots of transparent objects one on top of each other

Use time based animation rather than frame based animation;
(if you need it I'll build an example of this and post it on www.flashontherocks.com soon)

Until then check the following:

http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/  (I recommend vector tutorials)

http://www.8bitrocket.com/ (Bitmap usage in games)

Regards,
Oliver